# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') sanity error

Tags: next.js, backend, sanity

the problem that i don't know how to solve it is (**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')**) basically i have no idea where it can be in the console i don't have thread only on the error page

[image]

**this is what my app looks like**

*app/studio/[[...index]]/page.tsx*

```
'use client'

import {NextStudio} from 'next-sanity/studio'

import config from '../../../sanity.config'

export default function StudioPage() {
  //  Supports the same props as `import {Studio} from 'sanity'`, `config` is required
  return <NextStudio config={config} />
}
```

*app/studio/[[...index]]/head.tsx*

```
export {NextStudioHead} from 'next-sanity/studio/head'

import {NextStudioHead} from 'next-sanity/studio/head'

export default function CustomStudioHead() {
  return (
    <>
      <NextStudioHead favicons={false} />
      <link
        rel="icon"
        type="image/png"
        sizes="32x32"
        href="https://www.sanity.io/static/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

*app/studio/[[...index]]/head.tsx*

```
'use client'

import config from '../../../sanity.config'
import NextStudioLoading from 'next-sanity/studio/loading'

export default function Loading() {
  return <NextStudioLoading config={config} />
}
```

*next.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental:{
    appDir: true
  }
}
```

*sanity.cli.ts*

```
import {defineCliConfig} from 'sanity/cli'

export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: 'production'
  }
})
```

*sanity.config.ts*

```
import {defineCliConfig} from 'sanity/cli'

export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: 'production'
  }
})
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@portabletext/react": "^2.0.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-sanity": "^3.1.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "@sanity/vision": "^3.0.0",
    "sanity": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and solve it by installing the canary version of next 13 "npm i next@13.0.8-canary.2"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).